# SQL check user activated and active Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, sql, joomla, joomla2.5

I have an complex sql query and i would like to check if user is active and activated in WHERE clause

The query is running on a **joomla 2.5**

Can someone explain me which fields Joomla uses/edits to activate a user and how can I do that ?

```
SELECT u.id 
FROM #__users u
WHERE
-- [many clauses]
AND 
[user is activated and active]
```

Answer (score -1):

In the `#__users` database table, you will see a column called **activation**.

- **empty** = activated
- **string** = still requires activation

So in your query, you can simply use:

```
AND activation = null
```

Just for reference, I hope you're using [Joomla methods for your database query](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase) and not native SQL ;)

Comment: I only have a colum named activation which contains some values like `ffd5fbe5246c4da0957d7a5ec5f044de:$1$a20c55b9$`. Sometimes, the fields are blank.

Bu I don't have any `activated` field

Comment: Do you have something else to try ? :)

Comment: @FabienPapet - I've updated my answer, made a little mistake. If this doesn't work, please add your full query to your question so I know exactly how you're doing this.

Comment: actually, the `activation` column can also be empty when a user requests a password reset. I'm not able to find a clear documentation about the `activation` column, however your answer is currently wrong: you are treating users who reset their passwords as _not active_.